# Data migration from SQL Server to Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle, migration, data-migration

I am working on database migration project. Connecting to SQL Server using Oracle gateway. 
`Image` datatype in SQL Server is migrated to blob data in Oracle. But when I try to insert the data using insert command it gives an error.

SQL Server table:

```
create table xyz ([Image_Data] [image] NULL )
```

Oracle table:

```
create table xyz (Image_data BLOB null)
```

Insert command used:

```
insert into xyz
select * from xyz@sqldb;
```

Error message:

> SQL Error: ORA-00997: illegal use of LONG datatype
>   00997. 00000 -  "illegal use of LONG datatype"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ODBC is mapping SQL Server column to Oracle's LONG data type. It is not that easy to handle it.

The best way is to use DBMS_SQL package.

Here you can find useful notes:

http://ellebaek.wordpress.com/2010/12/06/converting-a-long-column-to-a-clob-on-the-fly/

Comment: May be I left with no other option.

Comment: The other option in adjustment at ODBC level. There is bunch of parameters that you can set up.

Answer (score 0):

We have successfully migrated the data with DTS Tool.